# How do I re-create my Mavenmate project and preserve Git history?

Tags: mavensmate, git

I have been developing a SF project using Mavensmate and Sublime Text. The code is in Git and hosted on Bitbucket.

I had to move to a different Sandbox to continue working but something is not right with my project as defined in Mavensmate.

I have:

1. A remote git repository with all branches.
2. A local PC project with a git repository.
3. I have a project in Mavensmate that points to my local code but seems to point to the wrong Sandbox.

I propose to do the following to reinitialise my project:

1. Rename my local PC project directory to project-old.
2. Create a new project as project-new on Mavensmate.
3. Perform a `git init` in the new project directory.
4. Set up my remote Bitbucket repository as a remote ORIGIN for project-new.
5. Pull all commits from ORIGIN into project-new.
6. Perform a Mavensmate `Compile Project` to sync the code in the Sandbox.

Is this a reasonable approach?

Is there a better approach?

Comment: I'm also interested in how to re-open a Salesforce project on a new PC. How do I create a Mavensmate project on a PC starting from a remote Git repository? - This is probably the key question.